# Reporting on number of times a user has moved a certain status

Tags: jira, jql

I need to write jql as a dashboard or filter to report how many times a user moved tickets from status A to Status B.

The end goal is to find out how many times developers have moved tickets from doing to at code review and get the user who did that status change to allow aggregation.

Can this be achieved in Jira cloud?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the issues by the following jql;

```
status changed FROM stateA TO stateB by theUser
```

Note: This is for single user, and tested on on-prem installation. Jira cloud may also have the same syntax imo.